# Azure DevTest lab : ResourceGroupNotFound error

Tags: azure, azure-devtest-labs

I am trying to create a VM out of a custom image in dev test lab using  `az lab vm create ..`  command.

I end up getting an error :

> Message: Resource group '.....' could not be found.

I made sure that the resource group name I am passing in, is the same as the one which is listed under "Resource Group" in the lab's Overview tab.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: are you using right subscription?

Comment: That was the problem. Used "az account set --subscription" to set the correct subscription.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case the az was setup to use another subscription, changing the subscription fixed the issue